# jQuery callbacks firing too early

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, callback

I have a problem when assigning functions to the click event of a button in IE 7 with jQuery. Something like the following works fine in Opera but produces an infinite loop in IE:

```
function updateIndputFields(index, id) {
   $("#reloadBtn").click(function(){ updateIndputFields(index, id) });
}
```

As I understand it, an infinite loop would not be the expected behavior in this situation. But I'm new to jQuery so maybe I've missed something. Anyways, what should I do to make the click event of the reloadBtn button be set to 'updateIndputFields(index, id)' in IE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the key to your answer is in unbinding the event that you have already bound to the click event.  I used this on IE and, if I understand what you're trying to do, it seems to do what you need:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateIndputFields(index, id) {
$('#output').append('<p>' + index + ' : ' + id + '</p>');
$('#reloadBtn').unbind('click');
$("#reloadBtn").click(function(){ updateIndputFields(index, id) });
}
</script>
<p><a href="#" id="reloadBtn">reload</a></p>
<p><a href="#" onclick="updateIndputFields(1,2);return false;">start</a></p>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Each click should output the passed parameters exactly once into the output div.

If you don't unbind the originally assigned click event, then it stays present and you attach a duplicate click event handler to the event each time it's clicked.  Even in Firefox, not unbinding the event creates an interesting recursive situation.

Comment: This is what I assumed with my answer: that the callbacks were accumulating.

Answer (score 1):

or just use [.one](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/one#typedatafn) to bind the event

Answer (score 0):

Try unbinding the event before binding it.